# how can i use ugly slugs in wordpress using non-western character?

Tags: wordpress

hey
like i said in the question : 
how can i  use ugly slugs in wordpress using non-western character?
more details at : 
http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/post-title-url/

> If your language uses a non-western
>   character set, long post titles can
>   break post slugs. To fix that, shorten
>   the post slug to a single word.

so i want keep long post titles evenif i use a non-western character like arabic , so please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to edit differently the slug from the title, right?
to do so, like in the link that you've putted, click on the post's url in the post edit page, and edit your slug as you wish (as described in the second image in your codex link).